# How can I determine if a column is a temporal column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this table with temporal columns:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Profile](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [CreatedDate] [datetime2](7) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW START NOT NULL,
    [UpdatedDate] [datetime2](7) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW END NOT NULL,
    PERIOD FOR SYSTEM_TIME (CreatedDate, UpdatedDate),
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Profile] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
```

I'd like to determine if one of my table columns is a "GENERATED ALWAYS" type of column, this does not work and returns 0

```
declare @TABLE_SCHEMA as nvarchar(255) = 'dbo'
declare @TABLE_NAME as nvarchar(255) = 'Profile'
declare @COLUMN_NAME as nvarchar(255) = 'CreatedDate'

select COLUMNPROPERTY(object_id('[' + @TABLE_SCHEMA + '].[' + @TABLE_NAME + ']'), @COLUMN_NAME, 'IsComputed')
```

Comment: An answer (now deleted) was referenced in [a meta question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/384355/could-chatgpt-be-a-viable-way-to-answer-peoples-questions/384359#384359). See also *[How do you plan on tackling ChatGPT answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421778/)*,

Answer (score 1):

Based on another answer, I was able to figure it out, the code below will return 1 (for row last updated date) or 2 (for row start date) if it's a generated always column, or 0 if it's not

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.generatedalwaystype?view=sql-smo-160

```
declare @TABLE_SCHEMA as nvarchar(255) = 'dbo'
declare @TABLE_NAME as nvarchar(255) = 'Profile'
declare @COLUMN_NAME as nvarchar(255) = 'CreatedDate'

select COLUMNPROPERTY(object_id('[' + @TABLE_SCHEMA + '].[' + @TABLE_NAME + ']'), @COLUMN_NAME, 'GeneratedAlwaysType')
```

Comment: As well as `1` and `2` there are some additional possible return values in 2022 related to ledger tables (see [`generated_always_type`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-columns-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) in `sys.columns` )